# Can't run the second task

Tags: c

I can't select the second task. If I run the first task, there's no problem, I get the result. But I have some issues in second and third tasks. Even if I select the second or third task, the program asks me to enter an integer, which is used in first task. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(void)
{

int n;
int length, row = 0, column = 0, space;     // Variables of first program
int top, bot, a, b;
int top2, bot2, a2, b2;

printf("Please select the task: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

if(n = 1)
{
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");            // Program asks the length
     scanf("%d", &length);
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
    while(row < length)                             // While loop for newline
    {
        while(column < length)                      // While loop for stars
        {
            printf("*");
            column++;
        }
        printf("\n");                               
        column = 0;                                 // Resetting the value of column variable
            while(column < row+1)                   // While loop for space
            {
                printf(" ");
                column++;
            }
            column = 0;
                row++;
    }
}   
else if(n = 2)
{
    printf("Please enter the length of top:");
        scanf("%d", &top);
    printf("Please enter the length of bottom:");
        scanf("%d", &bot);

        a = top;
        b = top;

    while(a <= bot)
    {
        while(b <= a+2)
        {
            printf("*");
            b++;
        }
        b = top;
        printf("\n");
        a++;
    }
}
    else
{
    printf("Please enter the length of top:");
        scanf("%d", &top2);
    printf("Please enter the length of bottom:");
        scanf("%d", &bot2);

        a2 = top2;
        b2 = top2;

    while(a2 >= bot2)
    {
        while(b2 >= a2)
        {
            printf("*");
            b2--;
        }
        b2 = top2;
        printf("\n");
        a2--;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(n = 1)` isn't doing what you think it is. Turn on warnings in your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(n = 1)
```

`=` is the assign operator.
To compare, use `==`.

What you are doing is setting n to 1, and implicitly checking if the value is different than 0. So you always enter the if branch, never the else one.